# Why does Java have `void` methods?

Tags: java, programming-languages, return-type

Does / why does Java need to have `void` methods? [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html):

> Any method declared void doesn't return a value.

As far as I can think, every use of `void` would be better served by returning a status flag, the object being invoked, or `null`.

This would make every call a statement that is assignable, and would facilitate builder patterns and method chaining. Methods that are only invoked for their effects would usually return a boolean or a generic `Success` type or throw an exception on failure.

Comment: So that we don't need a special syntax to write subroutines. We can use the same one functions use.

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7560655/1394393)

Answer (score 156):

Because there is a a difference between "This function can succeed or fail and is self-aware enough that it can tell the difference" and "There is no feedback about the effect of this function." Without `void`, you'd endlessly check success codes and believe that you are writing robust software, when in fact you are doing nothing of the sort.

Comment: But whether it succeeded or failed is something to express by throwing or not throwing an exception, not returning a flag. And returning `void` does not say anything about whether the method or function is self-aware enough to throw as appropriate.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: The context of the answer is the question. The OP suggested that in all cases where void is used the function should instead return a status flag indicating success of failure. In that context returning void DOES indeed say that the function literally has nothing to return. Forcing such a function to always return 0 to indicate success will give users of the function false confidence that they're error-checking when in reality the return value is always 0 regardless of success or failure.

Comment: @slebetman Yes, I see your point regarding the answer context. I think it's still worth to note that it's not really the "right way" - but I fully agree, and it's a good answer.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel There's a large number of situations where exceptions are not the correct way to do things.  In fact I'd say its rarer for an exception to be right than wrong-  an exception means something horrible happened that needs to be accounted for.  An expected failure case should never use an exception.

Comment: @GabeSechan No, exceptions should be thrown if the method is unable to fulfill its contract.  If the method requires a nonnull reference but it gets one, thats an expected failure and it should throw.

Comment: There are many alternative syntaxes to fix that. The reason they chose this (awkward) solution is because C employs it.

Comment: As per Marco, many other languages don't use `void`. Pascal based languages use `procedure` if there is no return value, and `function` if there is.

Comment: @Gerry What is a procedure if not a function that has no return ? Besides inserting a new syntax here to avoid typing void would not help the OP's context.

Comment: @Gerry Some Pascal based or related languages use `PROCEDURE` for both cases, and simply elide the return type from the definition when there's no return value. Both Algol W, a Pascal predecessor, and Oberon, a Pascal successor do this, and all three were created by Wirth.

Comment: @Gerry what would be the advantage of typing `procedure doStuff()` instead of `void doStuff()` in Java?

Comment: @Andy Calling a method that contractually requires a nonnull reference with a null reference is most certainly not expected.  It's even beyond exceptional, it's strictly _wrong_.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel A decent amount of code, at least that I've observed, tends to use a three-state success/failure model: Exceptions are used to indicate that it was explicitly incapable of succeeding in that situation ("something went horribly wrong"); failure state indicates that it had the ability to succeed, but didn't do so; and success state indicates that it succeeded.  (With a system like this, e.g. `2 + 2 == 4` is success (result is the correct number), `2 + 2 == pi` is failure (still a number, just the wrong one), and `2 + 2 == Batman` throws an exception (not even a number anymore).)

Comment: For example, [`Set.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add(E)) returns `true` if it adds the element (specifically, it both adds the element and returns `true` if the element isn't already present), returns `false` if it doesn't add the element but was capable of doing so (specifically, it returns `false` if the element is already present),

Comment: or throws an exception if it's incapable of adding the element (specifically, throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if the set doesn't support `add()`, `ClassCastException` if the set can't add the specified element's class, `NullPointerException` if passed `null` and the set can't add `null`, or `IllegalArgumentException` if there's something wrong with the specified element that prevents it from being added.

Comment: In a model like this, `void` can indicate, for example, that anything within proper operating conditions is tolerable, with exceptions indicating that it's no longer within proper operating conditions.  It can convey a lot of information about the operation's robustness this way, while also preventing wild goose chases and false senses of security from always returning a "success" value (as others have already mentioned)

Comment: (Using `Set` as an example, a similar container that can store the same element multiple times could easily use `void` as the return type for its `add()` method.  Since the element will always be added unless an exception is thrown, `boolean add()` would always return `true`, meaning the return value would convey no useful information.  Thus, using `void` would indicate that people don't need to check the return type, and should just treat "didn't throw" as success.)

Comment: The idea that an exception should only occur if "something went horribly wrong" is merely an opinion, and one I disagree with. In an editor, trying to re-open the last file being worked on and not finding it is not "horribly wrong," and the program can simply revert to a new, blank document, but it is just fine to blindly attempt to open the file and catch File Not Found exception. "Reserve exceptions only for horribly wrong" is arbitrary. Exceptions are a means of simplifying error handling; it is and should stay as simple as that.

Comment: @Gabe this is language dependant. Some languages such as Python advocate the use of exceptions for normal flow control. Google LBYL vs EAFP.

Comment: @SandyChapman They can advocate it all they want. It's a horrible idea

Comment: @MatthewRead And yet NullReferenceExceptions are still extremely common.  There are plenty of other reasons though a method can't do what its asked, perhaps due to the state of the object the method is called on, or to some conflicting argument values or a combination of both.  Your logic is bizarre though; do you really believe its good coding practice to let the method blow up with a NullReferenceException instead of checking for null and throwing a more meaningful exception?

Comment: @GabeSechan "an exception means something horrible happened" - No, that's what `Error`s mean.  (In Java, anyway.)

Comment: @MatthewRead: If you don't expect functions contractually requiring a nonnull reference to be called with a null reference, then you have a very naive view of the infallibility programmers.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I agree that "no flow by exception" is the general consensus among devs; but I disagree with that idea. Exceptions shouls be used for _rare_ cases that are too uncommon or impossible to warrant customized code. This should include both unexpected _and expected_ fringe cases. As an example: would you not expect a calculator to throw a DivizeByZeroException if the user tries to divide by zero? That would be a case of an _expected_ issue, but it cannot be resolved any other way than by an exception (without changing the return type only to suit a fringe case of zero division)

Answer (score 94):

1. Because C has a `void` type, and Java was designed to follow many of the conventions of the C language family.
2. There are many functions that you don't want to have return a value.  What are you going to do with "a generic `Success` type" anyway?  In fact, return values to indicate success are even less important in Java than in C, because Java has exceptions to indicate failure and C doesn't.

Comment: > "What are you going to do with "a generic Success type" anyway?" — when writing generic code, a single value type (it's called Unit type btw) is very useful because it eliminates special case of functions that "just return" but don't return anything in particular. But when Java was first created, it has even less expressive type system (without type parameters), so there were not much practical difference. And now it's too late to change. More modern languages actually eschew void "type" (actually it's not even a type, just a special marker for methods) and use Unit type instead.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Java's `Void` type acts as a Unit type (e.g. for Generics), though sadly, it is different from `void` (side note: a cuddly kitten dies every time you invent a new type to fix the type you messed up in the previous version).  If anyone is not familiar with Unit types, this is a decent intro: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 it doesn't really act as a Unit type (at least in practical means — one still has to write "return null;" to return from method which has Void return type, and AFAIK compiler does allocate space on stack for Void references, not taking advantage of the fact that it's pointless to ever read these values), it's merely a convention to use it where "proper" Unit type would be more appropriate.

Comment: @SargeBorsch In what way doesn't it act as a unit type?

Comment: @immibis because Unit type by definition must have exactly one value, and Void doesn't have values. Yes, it's possible to use `null` (in fact this is the only choice), but null is a special thing, any value of reference type in Java may be null (this is another blunder in language design). And, as I said earlier, if you are using `Void` return type instead of `void` mark, Java compiler is not your friend.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Void has exactly one value, which is `null`. The fact that `null` is a member of most type is irrelevant to whether `Void` is a unit type.

Answer (score 65):

The *original* reason why the language has a `void` type is because like in `C`, the creators of the language did not want to unnecessarily complicate the syntax of the language with **procedure**s and **function**s the way Pascal did.

That was the original reason.

Your suggestions:

> returning a status flag

That's a no-no.  We do not use status flags.  If something goes wrong, we report it via exceptions.

> the object being invoked

The fluent style of invocations is a recent development.  Many of the programmers who are very happily using fluent today and roll their eyes if they ever have to use an interface that does not support it were not even born when Java was created.

> returning null

That would force you to declare a method as returning something, when in fact it is not returning anything, so it would be very confusing to someone who is looking at an interface trying to figure out what it does.  People would inevitably invent some otherwise useless class that stands for "no return value" so that all functions that do not have anything to return can return a null reference to such a class. That would be clunky.  Luckily, there is a solution to this, it is called `void`.  And that's the answer to your question.

Comment: Please provide a source for "The original reason...".   To my knowledge the real reason is because C was designed to be portable assembler.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen are you really, actually, asking me to provide a source for the claim that java's syntax is derived from C syntax?

Comment: @MikeNakis If that is the statement you want to make, you may want to consider rephrasing.

Comment: They were stingy with keywords. The current solution complicates the language since it is quite hard to determine a function start, specially giving any sane errrormessages if the code is not 100% correct.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen oh, I see, I misunderstood.  So, you want a source for my claim about C, not about Java. Okay, I sorry, I have no source for that.  But I think it is rather obvious.  (I used to program in Pascal in 1987, when I switched to C. My goodness, that's 30 years ago.)

Comment: It is not obvious. C was developed at roughly the same time as pascal by people who most likely did not even know it existed. Please do not state assumptions as facts.

Comment: @MikeNakis The claim that Pascal influenced C in such a way is highly dubious without providing evidence, given that C began as a series of modifications to B, which had no syntactic distinction between procedures and functions.

Comment: Okay, this is hair-splitting.  Java syntax is derived from C syntax.  C syntax is derived from other languages.  Somewhere along the line, there was someone who said "instead of procedures and functions, let's make everything a function".  And obviously, that idea never occurred to Wirth.  Does anyone disagree?

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure why such a decision **must** have been made. Seems like the designers of C and Java could have simply never even considered distinguishing between them (though the Java folks were probably aware of Pascal). Regarding Wirth, his earlier language [Algol W](https://everything2.com/user/dabcanboulet/writeups/Algol+W) had a tenuous distinction. Both functions and procedures were called procedures, with those that didn't return anything simply lacking a type name before the `PROCEDURE` keyword.

Comment: @8bittree: Code written in C is often called upon to call or be called by functions written in other languages, some of which distinguish between procedures and functions.  Further, some platforms handle procedures and function calls differently.  While the exact details of how outside code is called will vary among implementations, enough systems need a way to distinguish procedures and functions that it's useful to have a standard notation to distinguish them.

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure I understand your point. Are you saying C does have a special syntax for distinguishing between functions and procedures? If so, please enlighten me. I'm pretty sure it can't just be `void foo();` because the construct resulting from that has to also be compatible with platforms that don't have special handling for procedures.

Comment: @8bittree: On platforms where procedures and functions are called the same way, a compiler could treat "void x();" as equivalent to "int x();".  Such a substitution would also work, even on platforms that use different calling conventions for procedures and functions, if it were applied consistently throughout C programs which never interact with outside code.  If a C programs needs to call an outside subroutines on a platform which handles functions and procedures differently, however, the compiler needs to know which subroutines are procedures and which ones are functions.

Comment: @8bittree: LIkewise if outside code is going to call `functionWrittenInC()`, the compiler will need to know whether it should generate a subroutine that can be invoked via procedure call, or one that can be invoked via function call.

Comment: The *real* original reason was that by default C functions returned `int`, so a keyword was added subsequent to K&R to indicate 'no return type'.

Comment: @MikeNakis Pascal was designed according to what structured programming advocates then expected to be a good way of writing large programs. This included the separation of procedures ("subroutines that cause side-effects") and functions ("subroutines that do not cause side-effects"). Procedures were supposed to return values through their arguments, if needed. The practical experience that followed made it clear that while there's many benefits to this kind of thinking, it's also unenforceable and limiting, and there's benefits to opting out of the rigidity (Turbo Pascal was a lot better).

Comment: seems like people failed to mention that you shouldn't be doing flow control via exceptions anyway. Exceptions are precisely that, for 'exceptional' circumstances. 

 In particular states where you cannot easily recover from.
The performance of unrolling the entire stack sucks.

Comment: I’m objecting the statement that “the fluent style of invocations is a recent development”. That style was known when Java was invented, e.g. `StringBuffer` exists since the very first version. But that doesn’t imply that this style was deemed to be useful for every class and method. In fact, that assumption would be controversial even today.

Comment: @Holger sure StringBuffer had it, because it was thought as the most practical way of working with StringBuffer.  However, only StringBuffer had it.  It was not thought of as a "style", and it did not have a name.  ("Fluent".)  Even the builder pattern had not been named back then, and that's why the original StringBuffer was called StringBuffer and not StringBuilder.

Comment: @DamianNikodem The problem with that particular limiting theory is that exceptions *are* a form of flow control.

Comment: @Luaan I agree that the restriction is limiting.  But introducing a type (`void`) that represents the absence of a type has always struck me as at least equally bizarre.  I never did anything with Turbo Pascal, but IIRC Ada allowed arguments to either functions or procedures to be `in` (read-only), `out` (write-only), or `in out` (read/write) ... which seemed to me an eminently sensible compromise/solution.

Answer (score 21):

Some methods, like `System.out.println` does not return anything useful, but is called purely for this side effect. `void` is a helpful indicator for the compiler and for the reader of code that no useful value is returned.

Returning `null` instead of `void` means you would just get a `NullPointerException` the moment you use this value for anything. So you trade a compile time error for a runtime error which is way worse. Furthermore, you would have to define the return type as `Object`, which would be misleading and confusing. (And chaining would still not work.)

Status codes are usually used to indicate error conditions, but Java has exceptions for this purpose.

Returning `this` is not possible from static methods.

Returning a generic `Success` object would have no useful purpose.

Comment: Totally agree with you, the most simplest and concise answer.

Answer (score 11):

One reason is that it can be *misleading* to ever return anything other than, say, `null`. Example:

#### What should `Arrays.sort(a)` return?

If you argue that `a` should be returned so that the call can be chained (which seems to be your response judging from your question), then it is no longer clear whether the return value is a *copy* of the original object, or the original object itself. Both are possible. And yes, you could put it in the documentation, but it's sufficiently ambiguous that you shouldn't create the ambiguity in the first place.

On the other hand, if you argue that `null` should be returned, that begs the question of what information the return value is possibly providing the caller, and why the programmer should be forced to write `return null` when it conveys no information.

And if you return something else totally absurd (like the length of `a`) then it just makes using that return value really confusing -- just think how much more confusing it is to  say `int len = Arrays.sort(a)` instead of `int len = A.length`!

Comment: In all fairness, the programmer wouldn't necessarily be required to write `return null;` -- the JVM could just as well mandate that if control falls off the end of a function by way other than an explicit `return` or `throw` statement, `null` is implicitly returned to the caller. IIRC C does that, except that the return value is undefined in that case (it will be whatever value happens to be in the location used for the return value at the time).

Comment: The correct answer to your bolded question is, "a sorted array".

Comment: @BryanBoettcher: Did you not read the rest of it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: not really, which is why I didn't cast any votes but instead just threw out a snarky reply.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling: it’s a fundamental property of the Java language to prevent such errors, i.e. not to have “undefined behavior” if you forget a `return` statement. Instead, you get a compiler error telling you about your mistake. Inserting an implicit `return null;` would be better than “undefined behavior”, but not much. That would be useful only when the return type has no meaning, but where does the compiler draw the conclusion from, that the return value has no meaning, when it is not `void`?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Yes, the JVM could mandate something seemingly nice like e.g. any unreturned value is the default value of that type, but what would be the *point* of doing such a thing? Are you really gonna say `Object foo = Arrays.sort(a)` and *want* the behavior to be equivalent to `Arrays.sort(a);` `Object foo = null;`? Does it really look better to you? If you do, I'm pretty sure you're not in the majority.

Comment: @Holger // cc Mehrdad I'm not arguing that it would be a *good* idea; only that not having a `void` type in the language doesn't automatically imply something like "the programmer should be forced to write return null". If the `return` truly doesn't add any value, then the language can inject one automatically, like how in an `if` block conditional jumps are injected automatically.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: “If the `return` truly doesn't add any value…”, well, as said, there is no indicator for the compiler that a return wouldn’t add any value, if there is no `void` type. It’s actually the opposite, the first assumption is that a method declaring a return type wants to `return` something useful of the that type. And we didn’t talk about primitive types yet, which don’t have a `null` value, hence, any default value injected by the compiler would conflict with the range of potentially useful return values.

Answer (score 7):

Returning a `boolean` which is always equal to `true` which you suggest, is not only pointless (the return value carries no information), but would actually be misleading. Most of the time, it's best to use return types which only carry as much information as is actually available - that's why in Java you have `boolean` for `true`/`false` rather than returning an `int` with 4 billion possible values. Likewise, returning a `boolean` with two possible values where there is only one possible value ("generic success"), would be misleading.

It would also add unnecessary performance overhead.

If a method is used only for its side effect, there is nothing to return, and the return type `void` reflects exactly that. Potential rare errors can be signalled via exceptions.

One thing that could be improved, would be making `void` an actual type, such as Scala's `Unit`. This would solve some issues such as handling generics.

Comment: Fun fact: `List.add` does always return `true`, but that’s for being compatible with the broader contract of `Collection.add`, so `Set.add` may return `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Java is a relatively old language. And in 1995 (When it was created) and shortly thereafter programmers were very concerned about the amount of time a process took control of the processor as well as the consumption of memory. Returning void would eliminate a few clock cycles and a bit of memory consumption from a function call because you would not have to put the return value on the stack, and you would not subsequently have to remove it.

Efficient code does not give you back something you would never use, and therefore putting void into something that has a meaningless return value is a much better practice to be in than returning a success value.

Comment: programmers who were very concerned about speed would not use Java in these days anyway, because first implementations of Java were notoriously slow. So slow that many people who are currently not working with it are still under that impression that Java is synonym for fat and slow.

Comment: @SargeBorsch reminds me of an old programming joke from 20 years ago.  "Knock, Knock."  "Who's there?"  ... ... ... ... very long pause ... ... ... "Java"

Comment: @DanNeely and some time after, an AI-driven car crashes in a wall with full speed, not even trying to use brakes. It was written in Java. So, Java _doesn't brake now!_ (it was a pun in Russian language, can't translate it to English very well)

Comment: @SargeBorsch What you have works as an English pun, even if it lost some nuance in translation.  And translating puns is probably harder than poetry.

Comment: Pretty sure programmers are still pretty concerned about wasted cycles.  And there's some heavily optimized Java code in the world today just probably not written by people who would care about eliminating the void type to support method chaining.  That is to say - method chaining by default is still viewed as 'inelegant' when your method is purely executed for side effects without a return value.  Well, by me and mine at least.

Comment: Why couldn't the compiler optimize away allocation? If I don't need the value, the compiler just wouldn't have space for it.

@dcgregorya if your method is purely executed for side effect, it should explicitly state that. Have a side-effect type, or actual "this does not return anything" type. `void` is too generic and gets overused

Comment: Good programmers are *still* concerned with performance and consumption of memory, which makes unnecessarily asking people to return garbage relevant even today.

Comment: Good programmers will always be concerned with performance and consumption, the market is just saturated with mediocre programmers, and it has now become the norm to be wasteful with your techniques.

Answer (score 2):

I've read arguments that suggest that the second option (return `this`) should be the approach instead of `void`.  This is a pretty good idea but it the builder-style approach was not popular at the time Java was created.  If it was as popular at that time as it is now, that might have been the approach taken.  Returning `null` is a really bad idea IMO.  I wish `null` was not even in the language at all.

The problem now is that if a method returns an instance of it's own type, it's not clear whether that is a new object or the same one.  Often it doesn't (or shouldn't) matter but other times it does matter.  I suppose the language could be changed to implicitly return `this` on void methods.  The only issue I can think of with that at the moment is that if the method was later changed to return a new object of the same type, there would be no compilation warnings but that's maybe no a big deal.  The current type system doesn't care about these types of changes now.  How this interacts with inheritance/interfaces would need some consideration but it would allow old APIs without a builder style to easily be called as if they did.

Comment: I haven't used Java in a while, but is it possible to `return this;` on a static method?  If you do change the language to implicitly `return this` on `void` methods, what would happen to static ones?

Comment: @Cody Good point, this wouldn't apply to static methods.

Comment: On a static method the pattern would be to return the argument

Comment: @marisbest2 Which argument?

Comment: Well, if `null` were not part of the language, people would be using all sorts of sentinel values that mean "please ignore this argument/return value, it does not contain any sensible value". The problem with `null` is not the thing itself, only that it tends to be used incorrectly. I'd wager that this problem would only be exaggerated if the standardized `null` would be replaced with a myriad of custom solutions, where each implementation would behave differently like silently ignoring usage, or throwing special exceptions instead of a standart null pointer exception, etc.

Comment: @cmaster I've pondered this for a while and what I would expect is that if you need a null value (many designs don't) for a class you would implement a singleton object that represents 'no value'. The implementation of this object would depend on the design. Generally I prefer to avoid having nulls anywhere except in local scope (although I do get lazy sometimes.) Rarely, I need some sort of special non-value object and I use this pattern. This really cleans up code because you need no if(foo == null) guard conditions. You are entitled to your opinion, of course, but I respectfully disagree.

Comment: I agree to respectfully disagree :-)

Comment: @cmaster an obvious replacement for `null` is a proper optional type (like, `Maybe` in Haskell). The problem with nulls in Java is that there's no sane way to immediately decide if a value is nullable in practice or not. This leads to both of: unnecessarily defensive programming (checking for nulls where it's pointless, thereby increasing percentage of poop in the code), and accidental NPEs in production (if forgot to check where it was needed). Yeah, it's partially solved by annotations but they are optional, not always checked, etc. So they won't save you at boundaries with third party code.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I agree with that :-) My objection is against a language without a standard way to express a "please ignore this value". `null` works fine for this (fine = simple), but standardized optional values with solid semantics are definitely another fine option (fine = safe).

Comment: @cmaster I should probably add that I think to make this work in a Java-like language, you would need to require every class to define a 'null' instance.  That way when you e.g. lookup a value in a map, it has something to return.  It could even automatically define a `null` on each type that works like it does today.

Answer (score 2):

Another aspect:

Java is a static language with quite strict features. This means that many things that would be quite open or dynamic in other languages (c/f Ruby, Lisp etc.) are strictly determined.

This is a general design decision. The "why" is hard to answer (well, because the designers of the language thought it would be good!). The "what for" is pretty clear: it lets the compiler detect a *lot* of errors, which is generally a pretty good feature for any language. Secondly, it makes it comparatively easy to reason about the language. For example, it is relatively easy to create formal correctness proves in (subsets of) the Java language; as comparison, that would be virtually impossible in a dynamic language like Ruby et al.

This thinking permeates the language, for example, the enforced declaration of possible exceptions that a method can throw, the separate type of `interface` vs. `class` to avoid ambiguous multiple inheritance, and so on. For what it is (a static imperative OOP real-world language with strong focus on compile time error handling) those things are actually quite elegant and powerful. They come closer to theoretical (science'y) languages which are purposefully made just to explore some of these issues than any other real-world language before (at that time, mind you).

So. Having a strict `void` type is a clear message: this method does not return anything, period. It is what it is. Replacing it by the enforcement to always return something would lead to either much more dynamic behaviour (like in Ruby where *every* def has an explicit or implicit return value, always), which would be bad for provability and reasoning; or to massive bloat by using some other mechanism here.

(And N.B., Ruby (for example) handles this differently, and its solution is still *exactly as acceptable* as Java's, because it has a completely different philosophy. For example it throws provability and reasonability completely out of the window while putting a *large* focus on extremely high expressiveness of the language.)